# How can I calculate the time spent for overall training a model in Tensorflow (for all epochs)?

Tags: tensorflow, time, deep-learning

I trained a segmentation model in tensorflow and I need to print the time spent for training the dataset after finishing the training.

I am trying to find time for each epoch and then sum all times per number of epochs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TensorFlow Time Profiler to measure the time spent for training a model in TensorFlow.

This tool allows you to measure the time spent for each step of the training process, including the time spent for each epoch.

You can then sum up all of these times to get an overall estimate of the time spent for training your model.